# how to encrypt private messages so they can't be read by system administrator

Tags: php

I am not sure if this is the right place but lets see.

I am developing an system to send private messages from one user to an other use. Under the hood runs PHP 5.2.x .

Now I am looking for any way to encrypt private messages in a way that **i cant access them**. At the moment I have no idea how to realize such a system, where I don't know the encryption key.

My first idea was to combine it with something like OAuth.

Some more requirements to clarify the problem:

- Public Webpage
- good usability

Comment: Simplest solution: **Don't look at them**

Comment: Ya, Gordon, that was my answer too.

Comment: @nont didnt you say [he shouldnt store the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156870/crypt-private-messages-wich-cant-be-read-by-server-owner-developer/3156915#3156915)? That's not what I said, is it? In order to do the crypting *on the server*, you will need the key at some point. At that point, the server owner/developer can access the message, so it's pointless to crypt the messages at all, if the aim is to prevent the server owner/developer from looking at them. In that case, it's much less effort to store unencrypted and just not look at all.

Comment: @Gordon - well it depends on what you mean by "store". You could simply access it as an HTTP request parameter - and then never persist to the database. If you want to split hairs you could say its still being stored in RAM. But when most people say "store" they mean something like a database or a file on a hard drive.

Comment: @nont it doesn't matter how key or message is *stored*. my point is that as long as you do the crypting *on the server*, you can access the unenrypted message at some point. If the OP does not trust himself enough just not to look at the messages, then adding encryption will not prevent him from looking either, because he controls the server anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will never work if you're doing the decryption on your server. You need to do the decryption completely on client side with javascript.

Ideas for looking for information on javascript crypto engines:

- http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/
- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

If your users all use modern browsers with support for client side database storegae, you can use this to store the keys: [an example](http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/)

---

you should know, that it would be not very secure if you want the de-/en-cryption to be fast, or it will be really slow, because javascript is not the best language to do crypto stuff.

Comment: Nice one thanks, but than one user needs to send the key to the other user or?

Comment: if you use RSA, the public key can be stored on the server. You only need the public key to encrypt the message. But it can't be decrypted with the public key, for that you need the private key, and that can be stored somewhere on the client side

Answer (score 3):

what about RSA and other public-key cryptography? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: Note, this is not something you should implement yourself. Try PGP

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Diffie-Hellman protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange) to generate encryption keys that are only known to the users.

But as a user, you have to have access to those keys in order to read your messages. So you'd have to find a way to store the key at the client instead of your server, otherwise you'd still be able to decrypt the messages. This would be quite a challenge for a PHP site, so I doubt it can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just don't store the key?

Comment: And how does the user encrypts an "mail" without an key? If he sends the key with an post requests than iam able to capture it.

Comment: well, you could encrypt the message and then throw away the key. when he wants to decrypt he needs to enter it again. Of course, if you don't want the possibility of even seeing the key, then the Andrey's suggestion is good, you need public key cryptography.